# c#:Error Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

I am proceeding with this small project for Test Automation. I am using C# with Selinium Webdriver, And I encountered a blocker, some Webelements are not visible or let me say has property 'Displayed' set to 'false', and so I cannot perform any action on those Webelements(for instance click a checkbox), I have tried to Google a little bit some have suggested resizing the browser window from within the code, Whitch didn't help, Also I found some hints about using Javascript to solve the problem, but as I am not aware how I can use Javascript code from C# I didn't make it. Any helpful thoughts is much appreciated 
(Also just adding a note here , my problem is not related to how fast the test executes , because i get the issue while the project is in debug mode and have break points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my particular issue and it was like follow ,
Lets say i would like to get a element 'input' and that element have the parameter Displayed set to 'false' 
I tried to look up successively the previous parent web element in the tree .and once i found the closest parent Webelement  i was able to manipulate the input element ,
 I am not sure why its working in this way , but it solved my problem !